# Math Behind Linear Regression

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

Am trying to understand math behind Linear Regression and i have verified in multiple sites that Linear Regression works under OLS method with y=mx+c to get best fit line

So in order to calculate intercept and slope we use below formula(if am not wrong)

m = sum of[ (x-mean(x)) (y-mean(y)) ] / sum of[(x-mean(x))]

c = mean(y) - b1(mean(x))

So with this we get x and c values to substitute in above equation to get y predicted values and can predict for newer x values.

But my doubt is when does "Gradient Descent" used. I understood it is also used for calculating co-efficients only in such a way it reduces the cost function by finding local minima value.

Please help me in this

1. Are this two having separate functions in python/R.
2. Or linear regression by default works on Gradient Descent(if so then when does above formula used for calculating m and c values)

Comment: This is not on-topic for StackOverflow, which is for programming questions. This is better suite for [statistics.se]

Comment: But anyway, gradient descent is a numerical method to solve the problem that the ordinary least squares method analytically estimates. Gradient descent is applicable to not only linear regression but various optimization problems